# Add new row immediately upon adding new item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid like this:

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Things}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Whatever" Binding="{Binding Blah}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>     
</DataGrid>
```

Things and Thing look like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things { get; set; }
```

.

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }

    public Thing() { }
}
```

The default behavior for the datagrid is to start with a new empty line at the bottom. When I begin to edit any property of that line, a new Thing is created and added to the Things collection. However a new blank line is not displayed until I finish editing (ie press the enter button or select a new row/column). Is there a way (preferably one that doesn't violate MVVM) to make this new blank line show immediately after I begin editing?

This is the starting point:

[image: Starting Point]

This is after double clicking the blank line and editing:

[image: Editing]

When I finish editing, a new blank line appears:

[image: New Blank Line]

But here is what I want (New blank line while editing):

[image: New Blank Line While Editing]

Comment: Why do you want the object to be added immediately as soon you place a double click on a new line's cell???

Comment: So if I understand correctly. You are wanting a new line in the bottom to be created underneath as you edit the row above?

Comment: Not sure if I get you right but you do not want each line to be added automantically. You want that behavior only when the edit is finished since you might start typing into a line and then decide to throw it away. Therefore only when finished editing the changes apply.

Comment: @devhedgehog That's a good point, how do you "throw the line away". I don't personally agree with this either but I had trouble coming up with a good reason not to do it.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Correct, a new *blank* line

Comment: @devhedgehog It looks like the item is added to the list as soon as i begin editing, so it still gets added/removed regardless of whether I delete the line before or after the new blank line is created.

Comment: @Justin984 I thought you want the behavior that after you edited the line it shall be added. I think I misunderstood you completely. Now I know you are asking to be always a line ahead right?

Comment: See pictures for clarification

Comment: Did you ever come up with a working fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

To get the behavior you want, you're going to need to hook up an event to the datagrid's **`PreparingCellForEdit`**, which gets fired whenever the cell goes into edit mode.

From this event, you can then check to see if the next row exists (current cell index + 1), and if it doesn't, go ahead and create it at that point.

I believe this will then create the desired effect of having the new row added as soon as you start to edit the cell.

For example, the `PreparingCellForEdit` event handler, this would add a new item (and result in a new row) whenever the last row starts an edit event.

```
DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

if (dataGrid == null)
{
    return; 
}

int currentRow = e.Row.GetIndex();

if (dataGrid.Items.Count - 1 <= currentRow)
{
    Things.Add(new Thing());
}
```

Since you're binding to a collection, you'll have to add a new item to the collection instead of adding a new item directly to the data grid.  Since you're using an **`ObservableCollection`**, it should automatically update to reflect a new row.

However, this would result in you always have an extra `Thing` in your collection, which you may not want.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I'm looking for is not a new item to be added to the list, but a *blank* row to be added. For example, the first and third pictures in the description have a blank row which does not correspond to an item in the list. That's what I want to display as soon as editing begins.

Comment: You'll probably have to modify the datagrid template to achieve this, otherwise I believe the only option is to add an item to the list as described, which will result in blank row.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Probably you might want to persist the cell editing focus so you can use *dataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, **false**);*

Take a look here:

[Add blank row to WPF DataGrid right after new item has been added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209177/add-blank-row-to-wpf-datagrid-right-after-new-item-has-been-added)