# Add blank row to WPF DataGrid right after new item has been added

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The default behavior of DataGrid is when I click on a blank row also known as the NewItemPlaceholder then new row is added and blank row dissapears until I select another row. I use **DataGrid.InitializingNewItem** event to set initial values for the new row so the new item has all the columns filled. I have complex cell content and editing the cells won't create new blank row for me. But still I have to select another row for a blank row to appear. I've tried to select different row programmaticaly but it won't help.

Is there any way to show the blank row right after new item has been added?

PS: This behavior also poses a problem when I delete all the rows and use blank row to create a new row. Then I have no other rows to select and blank row dissapears forever.

PSS: There is a similar question with **CODE** and **IMAGES** and no answer [Add new row immediately upon adding new item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080280/add-new-row-immediately-upon-adding-new-item)

Comment: Perhaps you could handle the CollectionChanged event of the source collection and add blank items to the collection yourself in your view model instead of using the DataGrid's functionality?

Comment: This is not an option. New item in the collection always have some default values. So I need exactly a placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also shape your new item in the **InitializingNewItem** callback method using the **e.NewItem** property so you can have correct item when the edit is commited.

**InitializingNewItem** is fired first following by **BeginningEdit** event.
Note that for the NewItemPlaceholder to appear you should also bind DataGrid to an editable collection with the default constructor declared and set **DataGrid.CanUserAddRows** property to true.

```
private bool _justCreatedNewItem;
dataGrid.BeginningEdit += (o, e) =>
{
  if (_justCreatedNewItem)
  {
     dataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
     _justCreatedNewItem = false;
  }
};
dataGrid.InitializingNewItem += (o, e) => { _justCreatedNewItem = true; };
```